# Deeper knowledge about ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'll try explain my doubt starting from the beginning. I have the following tables:

```
carts
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | created_at              | updated_at              |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | 2013-11-09 12:57:37 UTC | 2013-11-09 12:57:37 UTC |
| 2  | 2013-11-10 11:33:25 UTC | 2013-11-10 11:33:25 UTC |
| 3  | 2013-11-10 12:16:25 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:16:25 UTC |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

```
line_items
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| id | product_id | cart_id | created_at              | updated_at              | quantity |
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| 1  | 2          | 2       | 2013-11-10 11:33:25 UTC | 2013-11-10 11:33:25 UTC | 1        |
| 2  | 2          | 2       | 2013-11-10 11:45:26 UTC | 2013-11-10 11:45:26 UTC | 1        |
| 3  | 5          | 2       | 2013-11-10 11:46:06 UTC | 2013-11-10 11:46:06 UTC | 1        |
| 4  | 2          | 2       | 2013-11-10 12:08:41 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:08:41 UTC | 1        |
| 5  | 5          | 2       | 2013-11-10 12:09:03 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:09:03 UTC | 1        |
| 6  | 5          | 2       | 2013-11-10 12:15:48 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:15:48 UTC | 1        |
| 7  | 2          | 3       | 2013-11-10 12:16:26 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:16:26 UTC | 1        |
| 8  | 2          | 3       | 2013-11-10 12:29:21 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:29:21 UTC | 1        |
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

I execute the following statements:

```
cart = Cart.find(2)
sums = cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
```

The result is the following: `=> {2=>3, 5=>3}`

Untill here I have to say that it seemed to me pretty clear, that is I calculate the sums of the products based on the product id and then I collapse same products.

The doubts came later, when I tried to break up the instruction `cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)`

I followed the following steps:

```
cart = Cart.find(2)
items = cart.line_items.group(:product_id)
```

and I got:

```
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| id | product_id | cart_id | created_at              | updated_at              | quantity |
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| 4  | 2          | 2       | 2013-11-10 12:08:41 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:08:41 UTC | 1        |
| 6  | 5          | 2       | 2013-11-10 12:15:48 UTC | 2013-11-10 12:15:48 UTC | 1        |
+----+------------+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

and finally I executed `items.sum(:quantity)` and here, with my surprise, I got again`=> {2=>3, 5=>3}`

I came in doubt because I can't understand how I could get for each product id a number of quantity equals to 3 if I executed my `sum` on an object (`items`) which contains only 2 rows and for each one the quantity is 1.

 What does `items` memorize? The object obtained from `cart.line_items.group(:product_id)` or and SQL string which means that everytime I interact with `items` I interact with my database? I am getting a lit bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

Good questions. :-)

`items` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which represents a query. Not all operations on that object result in another database operation, but some do. For example, `length` and `to_a` do not access the database again, but `count` does.

Relations are also "chainable", so when you call `items.sum(:quantity)` it builds a *new* relation. In other words, a relation can be thought of both as a query and the results from executing that query. When you chain methods, you're really operating on the query component, not the intermediate results.